# Rails show index results from options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with Clients that have_many Contacts.  I would like to modify the contacts/index list with a selection of the Client.  So, the user selects the Client and the screen refreshes showing the Contacts for that Client.

I started with this dropdown selection:

```
<%= select_tag 'Client', options_from_collection_for_select(Client.all, :id, :client_name) %>
```

But, I'm not sure how to modify the table code that gets the Contacts:

```
  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
```

Do I need to use jquery?

Thanks for the help!

Update1:

Could I add `@selected_client` to the statement:

```
<%= select_tag 'Client', options_from_collection_for_select(Client.order(:client_name), :id, :client_name, @selected_client) %>
```

Then use this:

```
  <% @selected_client.contacts.each do |contact| %>
```

Comment: You'd need to load the contacts via ajax based on what client is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the info - could you point me to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it, note, this isn't tested since I just typed it up in here, but it should give you a good place to start from. Post back with your code if you need more help from here on.

```
<%= select_tag 'client', options_from_collection_for_select(Client.all, :id, :client_name) %>
<%= select_tag "client_contacts" %>
```

Then you'll need some js for the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#client").on("change", function() {
    var the_id = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("/client/contacts", {id: the_id},       
      function(data){
          var options = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
              options += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
          }
          $("#client_contacts").html(options);      
      });
  });
});
```

Then you'll need a route for client/contacts:

`get 'client/contacts/:id', to: 'client/contacts'`

controller example:

```
def contacts
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render: json: {@client.contacts.to_json}}
  end  
end
```